# Runnables started from AsyncTask wait for each other

Tags: android, performance, runnable

I have the following code inside and AsyncTask:

```
@Override
  protected ArrayList<Information> doInBackground(Integer... params)
{
 for (String[] info:informations)
      {
        final String[] infoFinal = info;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()

          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            Log.w("DEBUG", String.format("Runnable %s started",info[0]));
            synchronized (this)
            {
              publishProgress(InfoAsyncTask.this.counter++);
            }
            for (String infoInst: infoFinal )
            {
              try
              {
some long execution
...
 };
        runnable.run();
}

}
```

On the log, I see the following:

```
07-31 10:35:28.046: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 0 started
07-31 10:37:00.343: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 1 started
07-31 10:37:37.843: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 2 started
07-31 10:37:54.359: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 3 started
07-31 10:38:16.882: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 4 started
07-31 10:38:42.171: WARN/DEBUG(8983): Runnable 5 started
```

Check the timestamps.
 They should be nearly identical (considering some queue waiting).
I thought that when a thread starts, it immediately returns and lets the loop to continue.
What makes my runnable to wait for each other?

Comment: Why do you want to use threads inside AsyncTask? It is already a thread, it doesn't make sense to launch threads in threads.

Comment: I try to launch parallel processing in the background. If I don't use threads, how could I start parallel processing inside my single background thread?

Comment: Start parallel processing from the main thread after you have retrieved data. It can be achieved my launching multiple instances of the `AsyncTask` class

Comment: For the tasks to run, they need to gather information (it takes time so it is a background task). After that it is quite overkill to use an AsyncTask with attachments to the GUI thread.

Comment: Actually it should work like this: 1) run 1 task, gather information and return data to the main thread; 2) in the main thread run the for loop and on each iteration create a new async task and pass data to it.

Comment: Yeah, it is a viable solution, too :) Unfortunately I don't know what are the performance advantages/disadvantages of avoiding the use of the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runnable` is not a thread. It's just an `interface` with single method - `run` (which make it behaviour be no difference from other methods). You should use `new Thread(yourRunnable).start()` instead.

Although, consider using `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of bunch of plain threads.

Comment: I knew differently: "There are two ways to create thread in java:
    Implement the Runnable interface (java.lang.Runnable)
    By Extending the Thread class (java.lang.Thread)"
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

Comment: @Nestor You're not extending `Thread` class, you just implementing runnable.

Comment: @Nestor Further down the page you linked when detailing the Runnable approach: "An object of Thread class is created by passing a Runnable object as argument to the Thread constructor. The Thread object now has a Runnable object that implements the run() method."

Comment: @Dmitry Zaitsev: My bad, you are right, I missed the Thread :)

Comment: @Nestor once again - consider using some kind of `Executor` instead of creating all those `Thread` manually. Because most likely you'll exceed the limit of available threads and your app will crash.

Comment: I try to use it. Unfortunately my progressbar disappears after a second though my runnables seemed to be started. I use this:  final ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, 100, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()); and in the loop: executor.execute(runnable);

Comment: The best thread executor is the `AsyncTask` class itself. If application uses only async tasks and nothing else - Android will create only 5 threads and will manage everything on its own.

Comment: @vorrtex `AsyncTask` is not an executor itself. It is task. And on pre-Honeycomb you can't execute tasks in thred pool (instead, they're executed serially).

Comment: I ended up with a ThreadPoolExecutor. It works great on a 2.1 phone. Thanks, Dmitry :)